# Identifying groups in Group By NEW

Tags: mysql, group-by

```
select v.vehicleID, y.year, ma.make, mo.model, s.style, p.partID, p.dateModified 
from Part as p
join VehiclePart as vp on p.partID = vp.partID
join Vehicle as v on vp.vehicleID =  v.vehicleID
join Year as y on v.yearID = y.yearID
join Make as ma on v.makeID = ma.makeID
join Model as mo on v.modelID = mo.modelID
join Style as s on v.styleID = s.styleID
where p.status != 999
group by p.partID, ma.make, mo.model, s.style, y.year, vp.drilling
```

And I get results like this:

[image: results]

I want all the Volkswagen Golf, "2 or 4 door H", 11000, 2013-10-09 to have a generated column(alias) to have a groupID (such as 1)

then I want all the volkswagen gti, "2 or 4 door H" 11000, 2013-10-09 to have a generated column(alias) to have a groupID of 2 and so on.

**So basically each of the "groups" would have their own ID.**

Comment: you should really read this http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible, but it is better to have sort of a group identifier or a hash consisting of soms selections. For example

```
SELECT MD5(CONCAT(mo.model, p.dateModified)) AS group_identifier, * FROM ...
```

Then you have a unique identifier of each group, which is always the same, but not a number. When you want a number, you come up with some problems such as mapping a number to a certain group of sub identifiers. So a hash is probably a better solution for you problem.

Comment: interesting answer, i didn't know about MD5

Comment: This is genius. The concat of all the fields will match all the ones that are similar. Then the MD5 function makes it a hash which is easier to search for later on.